# Consulta SQL ordenando campos agrupados y a su vez mezclandolos?

Tags: sql, random, agrupación

Supongamos que tengo esta tabla..
Vemos que John, David tienen mas de una entrada y una columna Order al que podriamos ordenarse con un simple ORDER BY Name ASC, Order ASC

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui el dilema: Me gustaria poder generar una consulta en el que lo "agrupe" por nombre y ordene por el campo Order, PERO!! luego desordenarlo en el lugar que aparece. Algo asi como un agrupar todas las entradas de david, ordenarlas segun el orden, luego las de john, ordenarla por el orden..etc.. y a todos esos "grupos" aplicarles un ORDER BY RAND()

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta forma cada vez que hago la consulta se mezclarian los resultados de lugar pero manteniendo un cierto orden..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Increiblemente aqui la respuesta fue votada para abajo, la misma la realize en ingles, y la votaron varios hacia arriba por ser un problema muy interesante de resolver y por suerte me ayudaron a resolverla.

Comment: ¿Qué motor utilizas? Pregunto, porque la respuesta puede variar en función del motor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dejo aquí la solución por si alguien mas alguna vez tiene este problema.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62869122/sql-query-with-group-order-by-and-random-at-the-same-time/62871195#62871195